# Ruby - Best way to Store Tabulated Data in a Variable

Tags: ruby, hash

I am new in Ruby. I have data like this:

```
year | month |  foo 
--------------------
2016 |     2 |   4 
--------------------
2016 |     3 |  14 
--------------------
 ... |  ...  | ... 
--------------------
2017 |    12 |   9
```

I want to store that table in a variable and still be able to access the data in the column foo using values for year and month columns.
Something like:

```
data['2016']['2']
```

And get '4'.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's usually best to store numbers as numbers, so that'd be `data[2016][2]` under more ideal circumstances. This leads to a structure like this:

```
data = {
  2016 => {
    2 => 4,
    3 => 14
  },
  2017 => {
    12 => 9
  }
}
```

That's a nested hash structure in Ruby parlance. The nice thing about a Ruby hash is the key can be any object type and its type is preserved. Others will forcibly convert the keys to strings.

If you want all those values as strings you're welcome to store them as strings. Just keep in mind that integer values can be added together easily and strings cannot without conversion. For example:

```
total = data[2016].values.inject(:+)
# => 18
```

Comment: Looks like this is what I need. How do you define data? (ie: data = Hash.new)

Comment: You define it just like you see it there, that's valid Ruby code. `Hash.new` is for special cases, like `Hash.new(0)` which defines a hash with a default value of 0, or `Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [ ] }` which is the same thing with an empty array instead.

Answer (score 1):

Push it to hash json and get it by key & value:

```
data = {
    "2016" => {
      "2" => "4",
      "3" => "1"
    },
    "2017" => {
      "12" => "9"
    }
  }
```

Test: data['2016']['2']

Result: 4